# Should I always try to use the in keyword with sets rather than lists?

Tags: python

I often make use of python's `in` keyword to avoid having to write a long line of an if statement, like so.

```
if letter in ['a','b','c']:
```

However I have seen some people advising that a set is better to use as it takes less time

```
if letter in {'a','b','c'}:
```

Is this true in most cases or a particular kind of case? Is it worthwhile to convert a list of strings into a set to save time in this way, ie.

```
setToCheck = set(listToCheck)
for thing in things:
    if thing in setToCheck:
```

I'm aware that the list would **need** to contain hashable elements, but otherwise would it be overall a faster way of checking?

Comment: set lookups are 0(1) lists are O(n) so as  `things` gets bigger sets will be more efficient

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: but in Python 2, the set isn't optimised, meaning a new set object is created each time you reach that statement. The creation costs can outweigh a membership test against a sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the respones and link to the other question! @MartijnPieters Is the set cost still too much in Python 2 when the set is made just once before the for loop runs the check repeatedly? (I had it that way in my sample but I'm unsure if it's clear enough)

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: you'll have to do your own timings here; but for small sets it usually is not worth the trouble. You could create a `frozenset(['a', 'b', 'c'])` as a function local (or even as a *default argument value*, so it is bound to the function once), then use `if letter in local_variable_name:` to make this a local name lookup and limit how often that set is created.

Comment: @MartijnPieters,  how does creating the set outside the loop mean it is recreated each call? I know if you used `set(listToCheck)` in sa list comp  it would recreate the set each time but I thought the set would be created once and reused in the OP's code?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I *think* Martijn is talking about the case where the set appears as a literal in the if statement, and the 2.x compiler doesn't constant-fold it.

Comment: @Kevin, yes but that is not how it appears in the OP's code, `if thing in set(listToCheck): ` would recreate each time but the OP's example would create the set once.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: no, the bytecode for  `if thing in {...}` would create a new set object each time you execute that line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I am talking about the last example, are you saying the set will be recreated each time the `if thing in setToCheck:`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: see https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/cb41ab9a73df0dd0ec41

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: when you first create a set as a local variable then use `if thing in local_variable` the set won't be recreated, no, but it will of course be recreated each time the function is called and the local is assigned.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, ok, I thought you meant that the setToCheck  would be recreated that is what I was confused over.